# Problem deploying a Java web app w/MySQL into a Digitalocean Ubuntu droplet

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, server, droplet

I'm new doing server configurations and these are the steps I took, but the web application running in Tomcat 10 does not work.

This is my project structure:

[image]
[image]

- Installed MySQL into Droplet
- Installed Tomcat into Droplet
- Put the MySQL connector .JAR file into the /tomcat/lib folder
- Enabled SSL connections into 4334 port
- Cloned Github repository into /webapps folder

[image]

- Added database connector into context.xml in /conf and created META-INF/context.xml folder into the server folder.

Tomcat runs *without errors*. But server does not work. It works perfectlty in Windows. It's a project where a customer sends an order and there is a mail service.

[image]

Maybe there are some things I have to do inside the project before uploading it into the server? I tried with .war files and it didn't work. The logs:

```
15-Jul-2021 13:12:11.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:11.597 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:11.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:11.727 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:11.763 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.142 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.8
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 25 2021 23:05:41 UTC
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.8.0
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.0-77-generic
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Ubuntu
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.216 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.216 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.217 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.219 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.225 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
15-Jul-2021 13:12:14.231 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.546 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2193] milliseconds
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.695 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = TestDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "jdbc/TestDB" for "global" property
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.894 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.895 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.8]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.899 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.beforeStart Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.917 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:16.628 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:16.823 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [905] ms
15-Jul-2021 13:12:16.824 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:16.916 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:16.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [103] ms
15-Jul-2021 13:12:16.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/server-pulsar]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.021 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.052 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/server-pulsar] has finished in [122] ms
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.053 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.677 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.815 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [761] ms
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.817 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.876 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [68] ms
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.952 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.960 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [74] ms
15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.971 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Jul-2021 13:12:18.024 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [2379] milliseconds
```

Any help would be truly appreciated =)

Comment: `15-Jul-2021 13:12:15.899 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.beforeStart Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost]` is something to give attention to. Check the permissions are there for the user under which Tomcat (java) is running. You might need to create the path manually depending on your code

Comment: Also note that while you've opened port 4334, Tomcat is not reporting it (It should log like `15-Jul-2021 13:12:17.971 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]` with that port instead of 8080). My guess is that you can't access port 8080, but have you tried?

Comment: Good catch g00se! I didn't see that SEVERE warning. Jetto, thanks for the reply. I will check again the ports